# Monaca Debugger Showing Unrendered HTML (Android)

Tags: android, monaca

I just downloaded the Monaca Debugger version 3.2.1 onto my Samsung Galaxy S5. I attempted to debug a very basic app but the app is displayed as unrendered HTML (basically just one long string of HTML text) on the debugger. Does anyone know the cause for this and / or how to fix it?

## Debugger Output

[image: Debugger Output]

Comment: the application is correctly displayed with the preview option inside Monaca? can you provide a sample of your code?

Comment: Yep. Code runs fine in the preview window. I am down to running one of the default templates (the push / pop page template).